# SQL if exists then "Yes' else "No' in a new column

Tags: sql

I would like to create a new column in a table. If the primary key exists in the other table or meets certain criteria, then return '**yes**' else return '**no**'. Here's an example:

Table 1:

```
Student
a
b
c
d
```

Table 2:

```
Student | Subject
a       | english
a       | math
b       | english
b       | science
b       | match
c       | science
c       | english
d       | math
```

I'd like to see this column added to Table1:

```
Student | HasMath
a       | Yes
b       | Yes
c       | No
d       | Yes
```

So if a student's name exists in the filtered table where `Subject = 'Math'` then the generated column will return '**Yes**', else return '**No**'.

Could anyone pls show me how to do it by SQL? Thanks very much.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would normally do this using `exists`:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from table2 t2
                          where t2.student = t1.student and t2.subject = 'math'
                         )
             then 'yes' else 'no'
        end) as has_math
from table1 t1;
```

Unlike Tim's answer, this is guaranteed to return only one row per student, even if there are multiple `'math'` rows in the second table.

Comment: Thanks it works well and saves a lot of calculations now that we don't need to join tables:)

Comment: After 3 hours of trying and googling I found what I needed :')

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```sql
SELECT t1.Student, CASE WHEN t2.Student IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS HasMath
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.Student = t1.Student AND t2.Subject = 'math';
```

Comment: You don't want the `WHERE` clause because it would filter off students who don't have math.  You don't want this; you want to report all students, so that logic belongs in the join instead.